# Article usage when a noun phrase is modified by "of..."

Tags: articles

A rule of thumb is that when a noun phrase is modified by an "of..." phrase, it is accompanied by "the."

- He is **the** author *of 14 cookbooks.*
- They are not **the** playthings *of whimsical billionaires.*

When it is not accompanied by "the," should I consider that the noun is not restricted to a specific one by the "of..." phrase as above?

- And it happens to come at the same time as **a** milestone anniversary *of the original moon missions.*
- This tall and tender cranberry spice Bundt is **a** textbook example *of a kitchen cake: beautiful straight from the oven, a little spiffier with cranberry icing and tempting either way.*

Can anyone pinpoint exactly what differs between the two cases?

Comment: I think there are several different things going on here. "He is an author of 14 cookbooks" would sometimes be ok, although in publicity you use "the author" to make him sound special. With "example" you use "a" because it's self-evidently an example. "the playthings of the gods/rich/etc" is a common set phrase (even though "the" indicates a specificity that may not be justified, it's kind of an exaggeration; "we are playthings of the gods" etc is also common). These things are rarely set in stone, but the general rule of specific/unique vs example will often apply.

Comment: The first two examples sound good, but the rule of *the* does not seem useful.